# If user quits app after AWS Cognito TOTP AssociateSoftwareToken MFA effectively becomes disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a user application using AWS Cognito and I have the whole authentication flow working great.  However, in a unique set of circumstances when the user specifies they want to use TOTP MFA (through my app), I have to call 'associateSoftwareToken' on their Cognito user record.  This all works fine, I generate a QR code with the secret and continue on.  However if the user just quits the app at this point, Cognito shows their MFA as being set but in the auth callbacks I never get prompted for any additional MFA authentication.  It's as if associateSoftwareToken is doing more than I expect inside Cognito.

I can find no way to detect if a user is stuck in this state to direct them to fix it and they never get directed to MFA anymore which is an issue as the site has PII and EHR information on it.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and know a way around it?  At this point the only work around I can think of is to store the software secret in the users record until they COMPLETE the TOTP verification (or switch to SMS and complete).

FYI this is written in react and I am using the [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) library, however I do not believe this situation is unique to the language/library.

Comment: did you ever find a workaround? Stuck at the same place.

Comment: I never found a workaround with amazon-cognito-identity-js no.  Only option I could think of would be to persist the generated secret (and that they need to verify it) until they actually do.  So it would be a bit of extra sign-in logic...but it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more and more fiddling I came to the conclusion that one has to call
set-user-mfa-preference and disable the software token before calling associate-software-token.
Once the verify-software-token call was successful I will call set-user-mfa-preference and enable&prefer the software token.
By doing so I can check the MFA status via the UserMFASettingList result of a get-user call.

This approach may lead to user that have MFA enabled but I don't know it (I'll just ask them to set up again). But it will never lead to users that have MFA disabled but I think they have it enabled.